# Gauge Symmetry in Electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In E and M we have that the fields exhibit gauge symmetry under the gauge transformations:

$$V'=V-\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t}$$
$$M'=M+\nabla \lambda$$
for some $\lambda:\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In gauge theory, the gauge potential transforms under a local change of section as:
$$A_{s_j}=g_{ij}^{-1}A_{s_i}g_{ij}+ g^{-1}_{ij}dg_{ij}$$
for some function $g_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\rightarrow G$, where $G$ is the Lie group. Knowing that $A$ is the electromagnetic four potential can be written as:
$$A=Vdt +M_xdx+M_ydy+M_zdz$$
then under the gauge transformation $g_{ij}=e^{i\lambda(x)}$ we have that:
$$A'= A+e^{-i\lambda}de^{i\lambda}=A+i\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^\mu}dx^\mu$$
How do I relate this to the aforementioned transformation? I have an extra $i$ and a sign
signature that doesn't really make sense, so I'm kind of at a loss here. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I guess maybe I could get rid of the $i$ by being hacky and saying we identify $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$ and just drop the $i$. Then could pick up the extra minus sign by bringing raising the indices to the get the potential back into a vector which would give me another minus. But then I would have to rewrite $A$ with a $-V$, so I don't really know to be honest.

Comment: Physicists have very good reasons to assume that $G=U(1)$, but if we only consider classical electrodynamics, then I think that the **addtitive** Lie group $\mathbb R$ is actually the most natural choice and you get the desired formula.

Comment: I would even say that the identification of the Lie algebra of the Lie Group $\mathbb R$ (constant functions) with the vector space $\mathbb R$ is more natural than the identification of $\mathfrak u (1)$ with $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

In the covariant formalism your first equations are written in this way
\begin{equation}
A_{\mu} \rightarrow A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} \lambda
\end{equation}
note that this is only true for abelian gauge theories. In non abelian gauge theories this trasformation became
\begin{equation}
A_{\mu} \rightarrow g^{-1} A_{\mu} g- i g^{-1} d g , \quad g \in G
\end{equation}
Now, in your example you are considering the abelian case (for example $U(1)$) and so you have
\begin{equation}
A_{\mu} \rightarrow A_{\mu}-i g^{-1} d g
\end{equation}
Now, for U(1) you can parametrize each group element in this way $g= e^{i \lambda(x)}$ where $\lambda(x)$ is a real function, so you finally obtain
\begin{equation}
A_{\mu} \rightarrow A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu} \lambda
\end{equation}